# As a deaf person in a country that doesn't have a lot of accommodations, how do I search for a job where my disability won't hinder my success?

Tags: work-environment, india, disability

I was born with **profound deafness** in India. But can read lips and communicate effectively. I'm a programmer. However, I'm a 1 to 1 person and this is an disadvantage in India. people aren't patient, they just speak the things and move on, they don't bother whether I understood them or not...

So I use IM and email conversations for communication. When I go out and talk face to face with people, 6 out of 10 people can clearly understand me which isn't bad though. I've been practicing continuously. But what makes me worried is: India isn't that much of a great place for handicapped people. People aren't patient, they don't adapt to us, understand our requirements. We don't even get proper facilities from the company sometimes.

As a result, I'm thinking of changing my job and moving into a better work place where people can adapt to me, can give me all facilities. How should I go about my job search so that I don't end up back in the same situation I'm in now?  Some people just reject me when I mention on my CV that I'm deaf, but if I don't mention it, I get to the interview and they ask why I didn't inform them.

Comment: have you tried going to recruiters or applying for remote Jobs? Also dont remove it from your CV, because being deaf is impossible to hide for longer than 5min.

Comment: Related: [Should a disability be included on the resume or cover letter?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12336/should-a-disability-be-included-on-the-resume-or-cover-letter/12349#12349)

Comment: Are you asking how to move to a new job or how to disclose that you are deaf to potential employers?

Comment: related: [How and when should I disclose that I'm deaf?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/71221/how-and-when-should-i-disclose-that-im-deaf) (after recent edit looks much like a duplicate)

Comment: I have profound hearing loss as well but I wear a hearing aid. Have you tried purchasing professional grade hearing aids? That would help greatly but not 100%. As far as jobs, hearing loss is a difficult subject. Most places aren't as nice about it because it's not a visible thing and anyone can say they are hard of hearing. It really depends on how tolerant people are in your workplace and it wouldn't help to state you are hard of hearing.

Comment: Please reopen this question, I've edited this...

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to try to get remote work where you communicate with the employer solely by e-mail.

Trying to fight the system to get an in-person job is an exercise in futility.

There are various job brokering systems and web sites like "Rent a Coder" that allow programmers to work freelance.

An even better option would be to find someone in the United States or Britain to work with. There are many independent programmers who are hooked into lucrative contracts. In many cases these one man shops have more work than they can do by themself. If you find such a person you can offer to do their extra work. Also, there are various agencies and brokers in the US and Britain that connect independent contract programmers with clients. You can try to get established with those firms.